# Sending Structure through socket: ERROR code 2664: 'int send(SOCKET,const char *,int,int)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-studio-2015, winsock2

I'm new to coding. I'm coding in Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows system and the code language is c++

I'm using WinSock2 header with socket version2

I need to send a structure from server to client but am not able to do so?

```
    typedef struct{
        int a;
        float b;
        string c,d;
    } Mystructure;
```

in the main() function 
 After building a socket connection, connecting to a client and creating a struct object 
I'm sending it as

```
    s= send(sock, (TCHAR*)&struct object, sizeof(struct object), NULL);
```

but compilers say **ERROR code 2664: 'int send(SOCKET,const char *,int,int)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *'**

Comment: The error says exactly what's wrong.  `send` expects a `const char*` and you're passing it a `TCHAR*`.  Those types are incompatible.  This approach also will not work.  `std::string` just contains a pointer to the actual data, and that pointer will not be valid at the other end of the socket.

Comment: Well! I was actually referring to this link for a solution: [http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/16659/](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/16659/) they suggested to use TCHAR* instead of passing the structure directly in the send command which resulted in stray values on the client